# Google Place API webservice find a place anywhere in usa not just near by

Tags: web-services, google-maps

I am planning to build a service using Google Place API. I want to locate the nearest office location even if it is located out side the state or opposite coast(east or west). I tested with Google place API webservice, it seem to return results only within few miles radius even though I have not specified the radius.

I need to get the office location even if its 1000 miles away. I am using the following url:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=42.3157363,-71.0527482&type={xxx}&rankby=distance&name={xxx}&key=<APIkey>`

Any help/ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Rank by distance is limited to a radius of 7000 meters](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6914) (undocumented at present)

Comment: Agree with @geocodezip, it was mentioned in this [public issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6914).